# SQL Server convert datetimeoffset to timestamp

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have a `datetimeoffset` column `DateEntry` in my SQL Server table. When I want to convert it to a `timestamp` format with this query :

```
SELECT  CAST(Table1.[DateEntry] AS timestamp) 
FROM Table1
```

I get the following error :

> Error : 529- Explicit conversion from data type datetimeoffset to
>   timestamp is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

`TIMESTAMP` in SQL Server has *absolutely **nothing** to do* with a date and time, therefore you cannot convert an existing date&time into a `TIMESTAMP`.

`TIMESTAMP` or more recently called `ROWVERSION` is really just a binary counter that SQL Server updates internally whenever row has been modified. You cannot set a `TIMESTAMP` column yourself, you can just read it out. It is used almost exclusively for optimistic concurrency checks - checking to see whether a row has been modified since it's been read, before updating it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=SQL.90).aspx):

> The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime
>   data type.

If your are **absolutely** sure, you can use indirect conversion:

```
DECLARE @dto datetimeoffset = '2016-01-01 12:30:56.45678'
SELECT CONVERT(timestamp, CONVERT(varbinary(12), @dto))
```

See also @marc_s's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script if this this is what you are trying your side

`SELECT CAST(CAST(Table1.[DateEntry] AS  datetime) as timestamp) FROM Table1`